# Assign lat/long to zip codes

Tags: python, r, reverse-geocoding, zipcode

I have a dataframe latitude and longitude points in R.  Using the [R data science toolkit](http://thelogcabin.wordpress.com/2011/05/02/r-and-the-data-science-toolkit/), I can assign these points to Country/State/County/City/Constituency/Neighborhood, which is useful.

I'd like to assign these points to 5 digit zip-codes (or even 9 digit zip codes!) in R or python.  Is there an easy way to do this?

Edit: I found a [file that contains zip code boundaries](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=8d2012a2016e484dafaac0451f9aea24).  Unfortunately, it is a .lpk file.  How do I import this into R?
Edit 2: I found a [shape file](http://www.census.gov/geo/www/tiger/tgrshp2010/tgrshp2010.html), which will be easier to work with.

Comment: try the package `zipcode` in R which has a comprehensive listing of 5 digit zipcodes. here's a link with a short description about what it contains- http://www.r-bloggers.com/my-first-r-package-zipcode/

Comment: @Ramnath: That will work well if precision isn't required.  But basically since it contains centroids you'd be forced to consider each zip code a circle.  Depends what his needs are.

Comment: @Ramnath: Given a lat/long point, how would I assign it to a zip code using the `zipcode` package?  My intuition is to use the distance formula to find the closest zipcode center, but intuition is often wrong...

Comment: @Zach: There's a `pointDistPairwise` function in taRifx, and then you can just take the min of that.  But consider carefully if this is what you actually want to do.  Zip codes are not circle shaped!

Comment: @gsk3: Thanks for the tip.  I guess I'll start with a shapefile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Find a zip code shapefile somewhere (.shp format, sometimes called
   ArcGIS Shapefiles).
2. Load it into R using the `maptools` package's `readShapePoly`
   command.
3. Create a SpatialPointsDataFrame to hold the points.
4. Make sure your projections are correct.
5. Use the `sp` package's `overlay` command to overlay the points into the polygons.

You may find `cleanLatLon` in the taRifx package to be helpful.

Comment: Where might I find a zip code shapefile?  How do I make sure my projections are correct?  As I said, right now I just have a list of lat/long points, with no associated projection...

Comment: **Projection**: As long as your shapefile is in lat/lon, you're fine.  Otherwise you'll have to project them into the same format.  Edit your post when you've got a shapefile and if you need to project I'll post more details.   **Shapefile**: Try here http://www.cartotalk.com/index.php?showtopic=4416 .  Alternatively, many university libraries have the ESRI Maps & Data discs on file, since they come free with a site license.

Comment: Alright, I found a shapefile here.  How do I import it into R?  It's a .lpk file: http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=8d2012a2016e484dafaac0451f9aea24

Comment: You'll likely need a .SHP file or to convert to .SHP . Not sure if LPK is just a wrapper around .shp or what....   Sorry :-(  If you have access to a copy of ArcGIS you can likely do it there.

Comment: @Zach, please make your question about importing .lpk files a formal question. That does not belong in comments. Making it a question will help other people later who search for the same thing. If it's in a comment it gets lost.

Comment: @JD Long: I edited my question. Let me know if that works or not

Answer (score 3):

I ran what gsk3 put together and it worked like a charm.  Here is the specific code.  I've also included the str of my latlong data frame for reference.

```
> # Shape files found here by state: http://www.census.gov/geo/www/cob/z52000.html#shp
> 
> library(maptools)
> library(maps)
> 
> zip.map <- readShapePoly("zt48_d00.shp")
> latlong <- read.csv("latlong.csv")
> str(latlong)
'data.frame':   2102 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ ref : Factor w/ 1594 levels ...
 $ lat : num  32.9 32.9 32.9 32.9 32.9 ...
 $ long: num  -96.7 -96.7 -96.7 -96.7 -96.7 ...
> coordinates(latlong) = ~long+lat
> write.csv(cbind(latlong, overlay(zip.map,latlong)),"zip.match.csv" )
```